# R igraph, plot(): error in invalid symbol coordinates,

Tags: r, plot, igraph, graphviz, invalid-argument

What am I missing on this `igraph` plot() setup?

- First, I read a GraphViz dot file using `library(Rgraphviz)`:

  `g2 <- agread("INDDGO/sample_graphs/viz.test", layout=FALSE)`
- Then, I plot it using (without issues):

  if (interactive())
      plot(g2)

This confirms the dot file is valid. On the other hand, using `igraph` and `sna` to plot the same input file, I get invalid symbol coordinates, and I don't know how to fix this.

```
library(sna)
library(igraph)
g.dot <- read.dot("./INDDGO/sample_graphs/viz.test")
g.graph<- graph.adjacency(g.dot)
plot(g.graph)
```

In the last line, igraph fails. Any thoughts of what I am doing wrong?

Here is the Error string:

> Error in symbols(x = coords[, 1], y = coords[, 2], bg = vertex.color, : invalid symbol coordinates

Comment: Turns out, `agread("INDDGO/sample_graphs/viz.test", layout=FALSE)` reads the input file, where as `read.dot("./INDDGO/sample_graphs/viz.test")` cannot, any suggestions as to why?

Comment: For me this error came up when calling `plot` on an empty graph